# How to change user role after checkout in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want that every time a user buys a subscription his role should be changed. there are three subscription plans which are listed in the website. first is free, second is business and third is enterprise. I want to change the user role once the user purchase the subscription. here is the code

```
function change_user_role_after_subscription_is_purchased(){
$id = $subscription->get_id(); // You can use this to set meta in the subscription
// Get the products in the order
 $items = $order->get_items();
 foreach( $items as $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $userid = get_current_user_id();  
    ?>

<?php
 // ... Do your stuff here
    if($product_id == 3523){
        $u = WP_User($userid);
        $u->set_role('enterprise');
    } else if($product_id == 3522){
        $u = WP_User($userid);
        $u->set_role('business');
    } else if($product_id == 3521){
        $u = WP_User($userid);
        $u->set_role('free');
    } 
     
 }

 }

 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created','change_user_role_after_subscription_is_purchased');
```

But I am getting the internal server error while checkout. How to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you look in the WP or server error log to see the error? Internal server error doesn't really explain much, just that something's wrong with your code or the logic behind it.

Comment: WP_User() class was generating some sort of error but when I used wp_get_current_user() it solved the problem.